# adb: failed to stat apk : No such file or directory

Tags: pycharm, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildozer

when trying to install an APK using buildozer under WSL (windows subsystem under linux) I get:

```
joachim@Laptop-MJ:/mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture$ /home/joachim/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r "/mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture/bin/takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to stat /mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture/bin/takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk: No such file or directory
```

but when I run stat I get for the same file:

```
joachim@Laptop-MJ:/mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture$ stat /mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture/bin/takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
  File: /mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture/bin/takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
  Size: 28205421        Blocks: 55096      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 30h/48d Inode: 281474977440833  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ joachim)   Gid: ( 1000/ joachim)
Access: 2022-08-26 14:18:29.666167600 +0200
Modify: 2022-08-26 14:18:29.666167600 +0200
Change: 2022-08-26 14:18:29.666167600 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Please note that I have downloaded the windows version of adb and replaced it in buildozer (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Using-Buildozer-on-windows-10-using-WSL). The adb command seems to work:

```
joachim@Laptop-MJ:/mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture$ adb devices
List of devices attached
ce11171b6a4d221204      device
```

What's wrong here?

Update: When I use a powershell under native windows it works:

```
PS D:\Joachim\PycharmProjects\takePicture> adb.exe install -r .\bin\takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

can I run a native powershell directly from WSL?

Comment: Is there may be anti-virus/security software installed that could block read-access to the file?

Comment: I can open the apk in an editor, no antivirus intervention.

Comment: I would recommend you to not use adb within WSL. Use the standard Windows version and use the windows path to the generated APK file.

Comment: Ok, so I cannot use the integration of adb in the buildozer command.

Answer (score 1):

A work around here(example with fish shell)

```
function ainstall
  echo $argv
  cp $argv ./tmp.apk
  adb install -r ./tmp.apk
  rm tmp.apk
end
funcsave ainstall
```

Then, use ainstall to install apk for absolute path.

You may need to modify the install script for your build tool to use the new command.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows Subsystem for Linux try this**

- Linux is case sensitive. Please check the file exists in your required file path and revise the path if necessary.
- Check the mounted windows directory is correct e.g. /mnt/d or if using an external directory e.g. /media/[username]/
- Check your file system has permissions to access the mounted directory
- Use absolute paths for both adb and the installation file
- In addition if you have spaces in the directory path you can escape those with back slashes e.g. "/folder name/" to "folder\ name" or place the full path in quotes.

For example

```
"/home/joachim/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" install -r "/mnt/d/Joachim/PycharmProjects/takePicture/bin/takepicture-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"
```

Note: The install command and attribute should not be wrapped in quotes only the specified directories

**For Windows Subsystem for Android try this**

I have seen this issue with using Android Debug Bridge (ADB) with Windows 11 Subsystem for Android (WSA 2311.40000.5.0).

Example file: **file name.apk** includes spacing

For the error "adb: failed to stat name.apk: No such file or directory"

The problem for me is the file contained spacing.

The solution was to use quotes at the start and end of the file path.

In my instance changing the following worked for me in command line.

```
adb install "C:\folder\file name.apk"
```

The folder for the ADB application was manually added in my Windows 11 Environment Variables in the **System Variables** ***path*** setting so command line knows what to use.

Otherwise it would also show the following error

> 'C:\folder\adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

If you don't have adb installed via Android Studio and you're just using the standalone files

- You will need to point directly to the adb.exe path when running the install command

or

- Manually map the path in the Environment Variables. e.g. by adding a
  new entry for the adb directory to the existing **Path** Environment
  variables e.g. "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" or your custom path before running the install command in command line

  An example of setting up the ADB path is demonstrated here:
  https://theflutterist.medium.com/setting-up-adb-path-on-windows-android-tips-5b5cdaa9084b

Remember to use quotes at the start and end of the path especially when it contains spaces or special characters.

```
"C:\folder\adb test\adb.exe" install "C:\folder\file name.apk"
```

Example output

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3235] (c) Microsoft Corporation.
> All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\System32>adb connect 127.0.0.1:portid
>
> - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
> - daemon started successfully connected to 127.0.0.1:portid
>
> C:\Users\profile>adb install "C:\folder\file name.apk"
>
> Performing Streamed Install
>
> Success